# Showing the correct font in Japanese

Tags: 12.10, fonts, japanese

I'm having a problem with Japanese characters using old/Chinese forms (神社 being the obvious examples), just as in this question:
[Some applications use "archaic" character instead of modern Japanese one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45977/some-applications-use-archaic-character-instead-of-modern-japanese-one).

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and the solutions there don't seem to apply anymore.
How do you fix it in ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fire up terminal by

```
Ctrl + Alt + T
```

Install ttf-vlgothic by

```
 sudo apt-get install ttf-vlgothic
```

Logout and log back in if you need.

Comment: Glad that it worked for ya.

Comment: Note: now (18.04) it's `apt install fonts-vlgothic`